# Missing wire transfer from Israel to United States

Tags: united-states, international-transfer, wire-transfer, israel

Over one month ago before I left Israel, I wire transferred funds from Israel to US Bank. As of today, US Bank stated that they have not seen the transfer.  I have contacted the bank in Israel several times by e-mail, but they stopped responding after the first two weeks.

Is there some entity I can contact to get this matter solved.  Phone calls are not an option, as language and time zone issues prevent it.

Comment: Hm. Sounds like you might have exhausted all of your options. Do you have paper work confirming the transaction?

Comment: I hope you printed a "receipt" showing that you wired the money.  Otherwise, you have no proof.

Answer (score 1):

The best agency to resolve the issue is a financial controller equivalent in the state of Israel. This would be equivalent to the United States'

> [Consumer Financial Protection Bureau (CFPB), a U.S. government agency
>   that makes sure banks, lenders, and other financial companies treat
>   you fairly.](https://www.consumerfinance.gov/ask-cfpb/category-money-transfers/)

To my knowledge, if the transfer never hit a US-regulated bank, the best option would be to pursue it from the sender in Israel. If this means hiring a lawyers to pursue the case in Israel, it might be worthwhile given the sum involved.

Answer (score 1):

After writing to the Bank, the next step is to contact the "Banking Ombudsman" of the said Bank. This information should be available on the Banks website.

The [Central bank in Israel has mandated that all Banks](http://www.boi.org.il/en/NewsAndPublications/PressReleases/Pages/01-04-2015-BankingSupervision.aspx) have a mechanism to resolve customer complaints in 45 days.

If you are not satisfied with the Banks response, you can [raise the grievance to Central bank](http://www.boi.org.il/en/ConsumerInformation/Pages/PublicEnquiries.aspx) via email under "Complaints on Banking Services and Information on Banks​ ​"